# Flask user auth with Spring Security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, flask

I have 2 applications, each with their own authentication system.

1. A java backend/js front end that uses spring security
2. A python-flask app that is basically just a website.  Auth is done through Flask-Login.

I would like to have a single sign in and session between the two of them.  Since the auth is much more important for the java app, I am leaning toward having spring handle the user auth... however I need Flask to be "aware" of is the user is signed in, who they are, ect.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are they both on the same domain, or are they on different domains?

Comment: different subdomains on the same domain.  different boxes as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle this would be to have Flask call an endpoint in your Java app, passing along the user's name and password - then have that endpoint return the necessary information about the user in JSON.  That doesn't get you SSO though (the user can be logged into the Flask application, but not logged into the Spring application).

The slightly more complicated alternative is to have the user *always* log into the Spring application, but use an OAuth redirect (Spring has [`spring-security-oauth`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) and Flask has [Flask-OAuth](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/)) - so when the user logs in from Flask they actually log into Spring, and then the user is redirected *back* to the Flask application with a token that Flask then uses to retrieve that user's information from the Spring.  That gets you SSO (if the user is already logged in, you simply tell Spring to redirect back to the specified Flask endpoint with the token and Flask uses the token to get the user's information from a Spring-managed endpoint, as above).